# how to change text and concatenate certain rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate certain rows in MSSQL but I want to change text in products name and concatenate only some of the products, how can I do that?

So I have 2 rows in MyTable

| ID | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 |
| 1 | product2 |
| 3 | product3 |
| 3 | product1 |
| 3 | product2 |

If I make it:

```
SELECT ID, 
         STUFF(
               (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Products
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE Products = m.Products
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS Products
      FROM MyTable m
      GROUP BY ID
```

Then all the products will concatenate
I need to change text in Products like:

```
 CASE Products 
     WHEN 'product1' THEN 'PR1'
     WHEN 'product2' THEN 'PR2'
     ELSE Products
        END
```

and also I need to use only several products : product1 and product2 only.
So the outcome should be like:

| ID | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PR1,PR2 |
| 3 | PR1,PR2 |

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the `CASE WHEN` inside the `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: That `FOR XML` trick is not needed since SQL Server 2017 introduced `STRING_AGG`. You can write `SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(',',Products) FROM ... GROUP BY ID`. To change the names you can use `CASE WHEN Products ....` instead of just `Products`

Comment: Even after the edit this is still a duplicate. All supported SQL Server versions have `STRING_AGG`. If you want unique values, use `DISTINCT`. You can use subqueries or CTEs to clean up the data before applying `STRING_AGG`, eg `SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(',',Products) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, CASE Product WHEN .... END as Product from MyTable) GROUP BY ID`

Comment: You have all the building blocks you need to finish the query, change `Products` to `CASE WHEN ...` and add `AND products IN ('product1', 'product2')` to the inner WHERE